# Regular expression for validate number with or without colon or decimal point

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regular expression which allow only numbers and decimal point or colon (:) instead of decimal point. Bellow is some example

**Valid:**

```
87887
8787.878
8878:98
```

**Invalid**

```
abc
989ab
8987.89:87
```

I have the regular expression `^[0-9.:]+$` to validate but its accepts colon after the decimal point `.` which means if I write `898.:89`, it shows valid.

Can you please help me to find out a solution

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty  of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: How about: `^\d+[.:]?\d+$`

Comment: So is `.54745` valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. Demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/DYCWyo/3)

```
^([.:]\d+|\d+([.:]\d+)?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
^(?:[0-9]+(?:[.:][0-9]+)?|[.:][0-9]+)$
```

- `^` - start string anchor
- `(?:` - start non-capturing group so that the start and end anchors are global instead of becoming part of the or clause
- `[0-9]+` - allow digits
- `(?:[.:][0-9]+)?` - optionally allow a colon or period which must be follow by at least one digit
- `|` - or
- `[.:][0-9]+` - colon or period followed by a digit
- `)` - close capture group
- `$` - end string anchor

https://regex101.com/r/Joe8oi/1

Comment: Man I suck at this :P Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^\d+[.:]?\d+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jYEQeV/1)

**update:**

If you also want to match `.1` you should use:

```
^\d*[.:]?\d+$
```

If you also want to match `1.` you should use:

```
^\d+[.:]?\d*$
```

If you want to match all combinations, like `.1`, `1.` and `12.34` you should use:

```
^(?=.*\d)\d*[.:]?\d*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jYEQeV/2)

Comment: This regex imposes a requirement of at least two digits.

Comment: The first `\d+` should probably be` \d*` to match `.123`.

Comment: Try my solution. It doesn't  impose a requirement of at least two digits

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Just saw your comment and your suggested change would completely fix this regex to account for all cases. Now if only Toto would edit their answer so I can upvote.